# Como obter X e Y do clique em Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-canvas

Gostaria de obter X e Y de um clique em minhas canvas.

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 800;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 600;//altura da área retangular

function Desenhar() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Placar(){
 ctx.font = "14px Arial"; 
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 
 ctx.fillText('X = '+ x,745,10);
 ctx.fillText('Y = '+ y,745,25);
}


function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(evt){
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < HEIGHT){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
 Placar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
Iniciar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="desenhar_circulo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um evento `click` para a área do canvas:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('click', KeyDown, true);
```

Depois inclua na função `KeyDown()` o código para pegar a posição do clique:

`evt.clientX` (eixo X) e `evt.clientY` (eixo Y)

É importante também saber a distância do canvas em relação ao topo e à esquerda para que a posição seja relativa ao canvas e não à janela do navegador:

`canvas.offsetLeft` e `canvas.offsetTop`

**Veja:**

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 800;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 600;//altura da área retangular

function Desenhar() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Placar(){
 ctx.font = "14px Arial"; 
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 
 ctx.fillText('X = '+ x,745,10);
 ctx.fillText('Y = '+ y,745,25);
}


function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(evt){
   
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

   // posição dos cliques descontando a distância da borda da janela
   var posX = evt.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   var posY = evt.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

   console.clear();
   console.log("Posição do clique: ", posX+","+posY);

    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < HEIGHT){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
 Placar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('click', KeyDown, true);
Iniciar();
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
  Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Você é um gênio! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Criei um método Clique, que é chamado no clique ao canvas.
Nele recebo o evento de clique, neste evento verifico se ele contem `pageX` ou `pageY`, se conter não preciso realizar o calculo para saber a posição do clique em relação a pagina, se não realizo o calculo com as devidas propriedades, `e.clientX` + `document.body.scrollLeft` + `document.documentElement.scrollLeft`, então obtendo este valor, realizo a subtração do `offsetTop` para **Y** e `offsetLeft` para **X**

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 800;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 600;//altura da área retangular

function Desenhar() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Placar(){
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";    
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
    ctx.fillText('X = '+ x,745,10);
    ctx.fillText('Y = '+ y,745,25);
}


function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener('click', Clique);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < HEIGHT){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }

    var px = canvas.clientWidth - x;
    var py = canvas.clientHeight - y;
    console.log(px);
    console.log(py);
}

function Clique(e) {
   var px;
   var py;
   if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
      px = e.pageX;
      py = e.pageY;
   } else { 
      px = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
      py = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   } 
   px -= canvas.offsetLeft;
   py -= canvas.offsetTop;
   console.log('x:', px);
   console.log('y:', py);
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
    Placar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);

Iniciar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```